# How to return a sql result based on values in a boolean column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here's the scenario. I have a single SQL Server 2008 table - Products - with 2 columns: id  and IsNotValid. The data would look something like this:

```
id     IsNotValid
1        0
1        0
1        1
2        0
2        0
3        1
3        1
```

I would like a SQL statement that would return a result set that would return all the records (2) for the id=2 - in this case all the IsNotValid values for id=2 is 0. id=1 should not be returned as one of its IsNotValid records is 1. Similar for id=3. The data types are: id (int), IsNotValid (bit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you the results you need:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT id FROM Products WHERE IsNotValid = 1)
```

Comment: Running this against the above sample data returns the 2 records where id=1 is 0. I only want id=2 where ALL the IsNotValid is 0

Comment: @soulia This query is *exactly* the same as approach 1 of the accepted answer, the one you said worked for you. Did you type it in correctly?

Comment: Hi Greg - Yes, you are correct. I must have mistyped something. Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: @soulia Cool, just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some ways

```
Declare @t table (Id Int, IsnotValid Bit)
Insert Into @t Values(1,0),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,0),(3,1),(3,1)
```

**Approach 1:**

```
SELECT * FROM @t WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM @t WHERE IsnotValid=1)
```

**Approach 2:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM @t T1 
WHERE IsnotValid = 0 
AND NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT *  
    FROM @t T2  
    WHERE T1.Id = T2.Id 
    AND T2.IsnotValid <> 0)
```

**Approach 3:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM @t T1 
WHERE IsnotValid = 0 
AND Id NOT IN ( 
    SELECT Id  
    FROM @t T2  
    WHERE T2.IsnotValid <> 0)
```

**Approach 4:**

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM @t T1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN @t T2 ON T1.Id = T2.Id AND T2.IsnotValid <> 0 
WHERE T1.IsnotValid = 0 
AND T2.Id IS NULL
```

**Approach 5:**

```
select Id,IsnotValid
from (select t.*, SUM(CAST(IsnotValid AS INT)) over (partition by Id) as sumflag 
      from @t t 
     ) t 
where sumflag = 0
```

**Approach 6:**

```
;with cte as( 
    Select  
        Id = Case when x.Id is null then y.Id else x.Id end  
        ,x.CountFor0 
        ,y.CountFor1 
    From  
            (Select Id,CountFor0 = count(*) 
            from @t  
            where IsnotValid = 0 
            group by Id )x 
    Full Join  

            (Select Id,CountFor1 =count(*) 
            from @t  
            where IsnotValid = 1 
            group by Id )y 
    On x.Id = y.Id) 

    Select Id 
    From cte 
    where CountFor1 is null
```

**Result**

```
Id  IsnotValid
2   0
2   0
```

Comment: Niladri - Approach 1 works well. I added DISTINCT to just return the Id and not the whole result set. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you tried something and showed what you tried.

Since 0 represents 'good' and 1 'bad' I would do

```
SELECT id FROM yourtable GROUP BY id HAVING SUM( IsNotValid ) = 0
```

This will list only these ids for which all IsNotValid is zero.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. SUM(IsNotValid) does not appear to work for type bit.

Comment: I'm sorry. I had no idea it was a bit type. Then Greg's answer is the best.

Comment: My mistake, I did not specify the data types - IsNotValid is type bit. I may be going to ints if this isn't straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another ways of doing it:

```
-- using CTE and a join
with MyCte as
(
select id from Products 
where IsNotValid = 1
group by id
)
select a.* from Products a
    left join MyCte b
    on a.id = b.id
where b.id is null
```